# Set html title from the first header with pandoc

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I have usual `README.md` as people create for `github`, etc. **Pandoc** generates

```
 <title></title>
```

I want to see there the first header in file. So if I have `.md`

```
# My README
text
## Second header
```

Pandoc should generate

```
<title>My README</title>
```

And it would be nice generate  from the first 1-# header. So

```
### Preface
# My README
text
## Second header
```

still should be

```
<title>My README</title>
```

Anyway I want to avoid extending my `.md` with metainformation which is not a part of simple Markdown standard.

Comment: You could write it as a filter, in python/perl/js/php/etc. The filter would just grab the first level-1 header and use it to set the title metadata.

Comment: @sergioCorreia, how? please explain.

Comment: why not use `title: "my title"` in the yaml front matter? Pandoc passes that to `<title>my title</title>`

Comment: @scoa, because this will not be hidden by other renderers. Not good.

Comment: For info on Pandoc filters, see [Scripting with pandoc](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html). I would suggest trying it on your own. If you run into problems, then come back and ask a more specific question about the problems you are having with your code.

Comment: @kyb, I have shown a python filter example in an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Pandoc has an option for this: [`--shift-heading-level-by`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL#option--shift-heading-level-by). The option can be used to promote or demote all headings in the document, and the first heading that's shifted "above top level" is used as the title.

In the case of a default GitHub README.md, the following would work best:

```bash
pandoc --shift-heading-level-by=-1 --standalone --from=gfm ...
```

The format specifier `gfm` stands for "GitHub Flavored Markdown".

The downside of this approach is that second-level headings are output as `<h1>` elements, which may be undesired. In that case, the most general solution is to use a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters):

```lua
function Pandoc (doc)
  doc.blocks:walk {
    Header = function (h)
      -- use top-level heading as title, unless the doc
      -- already has a title
      if h.level == 1 and not doc.meta.title then
        doc.meta.title = h.content
        return {}  -- remove this heading from the body
      end
    end
  }
  return doc
end
```

The above can be used by saving it to a file `readme-title.lua` and passed to pandoc via `--lua-filter=readme-title.lua`.

Answer (score 7):

pandoc -s test.md -o test.html --metadata title=titleName

Comment: Please explain how this solution helps in answering the question.

Comment: I'd add `titleName=grep -m1 '^#\s+.*'`  - extract first line begins with '#'. Thanks.

Comment: This worked great for me. `--metadata title=""` removed the title from my output, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: This adds the given title to the HTML of the page. I just want it to add `<title>My awesome title</title>` to the head section of the document. Is this possible? I'm already using a <h1> as my title.

Comment: `--metadata title="TITLE HERE"` didn't work for me, but `--metadata=title:TITLE HERE` did

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you have just some plain Markdown files - no meaningful filename, no YAML front matter magic, or such ... and still you want i.e. the output to have some sensible title; without to much manual intervention.
And it's pretty common for web pages that the title and the first headline are the same (look at the source code of this exact page: you'll find *'Set html title from the first header with pandoc'* in the `title` and within a `h1` tag).

For my purposes I have written a small Lua filter ...

```
local headline = ""

to_string = {

    Str = function(element)
        headline = headline .. element.text
    end,

    Space = function()
        headline = headline .. " "
    end
}

function Pandoc(doc)

    for i,element in pairs(doc.blocks) do
        if element.t == "Header" and element.level == 1 then
            element:walk(to_string)
            break
        end
    end

    print(headline)
    os.exit(0)
end
```

... and saved it as `first_headline.lua`

I can then use this filter for example in my shell scripts ...

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=$1
TITLE=`pandoc --lua-filter=first_headline.lua $INPUT`
pandoc -s --to=html --metadata title="$TITLE" $INPUT
```

... and in theory this should work for any input format that comes with headlines and any output format that supports a document title.

However, key point here is the underlying idea - with some tinkering this approach should be helpful for many similar use cases.

Answer (score 2):

That is easily achiveable with [lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html).

Create `HeaderToTitle.lua`:

```lua
local title
function Header(el)
  if title then return end
  title = pandoc.utils.stringify(el)
end

function Meta(el)
  if not el.pagetitle then
    el.pagetitle = title
    return el
  end
end
```

And now add following option to pandoc command line: `--lua-filter=HeaderToTitle.lua`

Comment: Similar solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56005271/2520247

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating a PDF, then an alternative workaround could be:

```
pandoc inputname.md -o outputname.pdf -V "title:My Desired Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `README.md` file, and you want to convert it into `README.html` with the first `level 1` markdown title as html header.

You can run pandoc with customized filer (take python as example).

1. save the following python script into `filter.py` file

```
from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Null


def behead(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == "Header" and value[0] == 1 and "title" not in meta:
        meta["title"] = {"t": "MetaInlines", "c": value[2]}
        return Null()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(behead)
```

2. add execution permission for the file

```
chmod +x filter.py
```

3. add execution permission for the file

```
pandoc -s README.md -o README.html --filter filter.py
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
pandoc -s README.md -o README.html -V "pagetitle:My README"
```