# Pandoc : set document title to first title

Tags: github, latex, markdown, pandoc

I'm creating a library on github, so I'm using a Markdown file for that, with the following structure:

```
# My main title
## My first section
...
## My second section
...
```

But unfortunately, when I use pandoc to convert this document into latex:

```
pandoc README.md --number-sections -f markdown -t latex -s -o doc.tex
```

the document does not have any title, and the numbering starts from the main title:

```
1. My main title
1.1. My first section
...
1.2. My second section
...
```

While I'd like something like

```
My main title <=== document title
1. My first section
...
2. My second section
...
```

I could of course use sed to change all ## to #, and replace the main title with `% Document My main title` but it looks quite dirty to me. What is the good way to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note: this answer applies to all pandoc versions > 2.0, but see the answer by @sww1235 for a simpler method that works with later pandoc versions.

---

Best to use a pandoc filter to do this. Here's a Lua filter that does what you need. Store it in a file, e.g. `promote-headers.lua` and call pandoc with `pandoc --lua-filter=promote-headers.lua`.

```lua
local title

-- Promote all headers by one level. Set title from level 1 headers,
-- unless it has been set before.
function promote_header (header)

  if header.level >= 2 then
    header.level = header.level - 1
    return header
  end

  if not title then
    title = header.content
    return {}
  end

  local msg = '[WARNING] title already set; discarding header "%s"\n'
  io.stderr:write(msg:format(pandoc.utils.stringify(header)))
  return {}
end

return {
  {Meta = function (meta) title = meta.title end}, -- init title
  {Header = promote_header},
  {Meta = function (meta) meta.title = title; return meta end}, -- set title
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As of git commit [88dc6fac5d](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/88dc6fac5d2d6f494e9c334261ecb40d3e156667) in Pandoc, you can now use the `--shift-heading-level-by` option in Pandoc to promote metadata titles to first level headings (+1 shift), and first level headings to metadata titles (-1 shift). This is available from pandoc 2.8 and up. Pandoc [manual reference](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--shift-heading-level-by)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Specifying `--shift-heading-level-by=-1` results in the document title being dropped.

Comment: @DanielWolf Did you miss using the `-s` option on the command line?

Comment: @YongweiWu Thanks, that did it! I knew the "standalone" flag, but I didn't know it had any effect on AsciiDoc output.