# Pandoc convert YAML title to header 1 to combine multiple files

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have written multiple articles in their own respective markdown files.
Each article contains its own YAML-header with title and authors.
Now I want to combine all articles for my dissertation, but I bump into a problem:
all titles and authors are lost; only the last YAML-metadata is used.
This is expected behaviour according to the [Pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), but in my case it is not handy (the first chapter is then called "Concluding remarks").
Is there a way I can respect the article/chapter titles and authors on the chapter level, yet still combine the documents?

I was thinking I could use [--shift-heading-level-by](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--shift-heading-level-by).
This works for all headers (h1 etc) in the document, but leaves the title unchanged in the YAML-header instead of creating a h1.
Do you know whether it is possible to replace a title with a header 1, without manually editting the source documents?

Comment: ha, I think we had this behaviour, but [it was rolled back](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5615#issuecomment-562237213)...  meanwhile, you should be able to [use this filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004886/pandoc-set-document-title-to-first-title)

Comment: I think I want the exact opposite of that filter, in the sense that I have a title and would like to convert it to h1. I'll see if I can adapt the filter you mentioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I just solved it for me:

Step 1:
I do not aim to generate the full output, but rather "chapters" consisting of individual files. I generate these as (temporary) markdown files (both -f and -t are markdown)

Step 2:
I printed the the default markdown template with pandoc -D markdown, and just added before the $body$ line another markdown line with # $title$

Step3:
I then used that template to generate a file "chapterFoo4Book.md" (pandoc --template=path/to/modified-markdown.md

Step 4:
Now I have "sane" chapter files that I then run with pandoc through pdflatex.

A Makefile conveniantly comnbines these "targets" (as make names them) into a target "all"

I learned today:

- Filters might see an AST that is different from what I believed [How pandoc lua filters can be used to add the title as the level-1 header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561584/how-pandoc-lua-filters-can-be-used-to-add-the-title-as-the-level-1-header#comment101596519_57561584)
- shifting headers down was rolled back as it broke too many things https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5615#issuecomment-562237213
- I just so love Makefiles ;)

Edit: Wow, that approach then even works nicely with --top-level-division=chapter