# How to combine some markdown (with yaml header) files into a single pandoc output

Tags: pandoc

I want to combine a few `markdown files` (0*.md, i.e. 02.md, 03.md and 05.md) with a file containing a title and abstract (index.md) files into a single `pandoc` output. All the files include headers like:

```
---
title: title02 
abstract: abstract02
---
```

followed by text.

The result is produced with

```
pandoc -o readme.pdf index.md 0*.md
```

and is nearly satisfactory. The title and the abstract is the title of the last 05.md file (not of the index.md file). The title of the 0*.md files however are not included.

Is there are possibility to achieve the desired output with a pandoc command or do I need to revert to a program to combine the files? What can I change to improve the result?

I see some similarity to [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62869694/pandoc-convert-yaml-title-to-header-1-to-combine-multiple-files) but the process is too involved; I need a procedure which runs automatically on different sets of similarly structured files.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc has a useful feature for cases like this: [custom Lua readers](https://pandoc.org/custom-readers). We can use that to use the input files just the way we need it.

The script below assumes that the first input file (`index.md`) is special, in that it defines the top-level metadata. All other input files are slightly modified: the title is converted into a top-level heading, and all other headings are shifted to accommodate for that. Likewise, an abstract is added as a separate section. You can customize this further if needed.

Use the below by saving it to a file `combine.lua`, then call pandoc with
`pandoc --from=combine.lua index.md 01.md ...`.

```lua
function Reader(inputs, opts)
  local doc = pandoc.Pandoc{}  -- the resulting document

  -- parse input as Markdown
  local parse = function (input)
    return pandoc.read(tostring(input), 'markdown', opts)
  end

  -- The first file is assumed to be special. Just use as-is.
  doc = doc .. parse(inputs:remove(1))

  -- Process each input file separately and merge it into the top-level
  -- document.
  for i, input in ipairs(inputs) do
    local part = parse(input, opts)
    -- add the title as a top-level heading
    if part.meta.title then
      doc.blocks:insert(pandoc.Header(1, part.meta.title))
      part.meta.title = nil  -- unset, so it won't conflict with main title
    end
    -- add the abstract under a new heading
    if part.meta.abstract then
      doc.blocks:insert(pandoc.Header(2, 'Abstract'))
      doc.blocks:extend(
        pandoc.utils.type(part.meta.abstract) == 'Inlines' and
        {pandoc.Plain(part.meta.abstract)} or
        part.meta.abstract
      )
      part.meta.abstract = nil  -- prevent conflicts
    end
    -- append the main contents to the result doc and merge all meta
    -- information. Shift headings in the part.
    doc = doc .. part:walk {
      Header = function (h)
        h.level = h.level + 1
        return h
      end
    }
  end
  return doc
end
```

Comment: Looks exactly what I have asked for and it worked immediately on my example cases. Impressive! Thank you a lot! -- Small point:    the abstracts for the 0*.md files were formatted as a "one word per line column" and I have no experience at this level of dealing with pandoc to see how to change this yet,  What need to be changed?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a small change, I hope that fixes the issue.

Comment: now i get an error: Error running Lua:
combine.lua:28: bad argument #1 to 'extend' (table expected, got Block).

Comment: Sorry, I should have tested that. One second

Comment: additional question: how to run the filter on files in another directory? If i add a path expression to the `--from=` with capitals I get an error message (without the capitals). I am confused by using lua?

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed it for real now. Could you open a new question for the follow up? I think I may need some more context or an example.

Comment: it is fixed - thank you. Will open a new question later tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: This works with crossrefs as well - only I need to add a single title line at the end of the combined text to preceed the bibliiography data inserted by crossref (it such data is inserted, otherwise nothing). Should be simple, but I could not see it from the `custom Lua reader` instructions. Should I open a new question?

Comment: It might be enough to add `reference-section-title: Reference` to the YAML.

Comment: I am impresse! it worked. Pandoc is powerful, but complex to master. Thank you!