# use lua filter for pandoc - what is correct path?

Tags: lua, pandoc

I have a lua filter (from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806890/how-to-combine-some-markdown-with-yaml-header-files-into-a-single-pandoc-outpu/75810635?noredirect=1#comment133737207_75810635)). The code for the filter is in file `combine.lua` in the same directory as the files to process with

```
pandoc --from=combine.lua index.md 0*.md -o res1.pdf
```

Now I want to apply the same filter to files with corresponding names in another directory and assumed I could just use a fully qualified filepath to the lua filter as

```
pandoc --from=/home/frank/Workspace11/experiments_SSG_related/booklet/combine.lua  index.md 0*.md -o res1.pdf
```

but I get the error

```
Error running Lua:
cannot open /home/frank/workspace11/experiments_ssg_related/booklet/combine.lua: No such file or directory
```

I have no experience with Lua, but notice that the file path returned has changed my uppercase inputs in lowercase.

What is the best procedure to call a lua filter when applying it to files in different directories? Where to store the filter? how to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in pandoc; I've [fixed it](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/cf8370f4e569c6a53d1115419eae4f3bce989176), and the next release (pandoc 3.2) should no longer have that problem.

For the moment my suggestion would be to place the custom writer in the `custom` folder of pandoc's data directory: we can run `pandoc -v` to find the directory that pandoc checks for data files; a Lua script placed in `custom/combine.lua` can be used by writing just `--from combine.lua`.

On my system `pandoc -v` yields

```
pandoc 3.1.1
Features: +server +lua
Scripting engine: Lua 5.4
User data directory: /home/albert/.local/share/pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2023 John MacFarlane. Web:  https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
```

so I'd have to place the file in `/home/albert/.local/share/pandoc/custom/combine.lua`.

Note, however, that this require pandoc 3.0 or later; pandoc 2.19 supported this as well, but searched the `readers` folder instead of `custom`.

Comment: Unfortunately, seems not to work here: I have placed a copy of `combine.lua` but get for`pandoc --from=combine.lua index.md 0*.md -o res1.pdf` in another directory: `
Error running Lua:
cannot open combine.lua: No such file or directory`. i have pandoc 2.17.1.1.

Comment: I think with older versions (pre 3.0), pandoc was looking in the `readers` folder. (Or was it `reader`, singular? Not sure.)

Comment: @user855443 I looked it up, `readers` was searched in pandoc 2.19 only. So I'm afraid the only way to get this working is to update pandoc. Sorry.

Comment: I finally got pandoc 3.1.1 and pandoc-crossref rebuild and now nearly everthing works (The crucial information I was missing is to call `cabal install pandoc-cli` to get an exec for pandoc!). Thank you for all the help!